# Select item as icon from ComboBox

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, image, combobox

I'm currently building some custom software in Visual Studio in VB.Net with an SQL back end. I have a list of account names that the user selects in a comboBox. The comboBox is populated via SQL query from a "Name" column from the Accounts Table using a DataReader approach as seen below:

```
Dim Connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString:=<Blah>")
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(
            "SELECT Name from Accounts as A", Connection
                                  )
        Connection.Open()
        Dim rs1 As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt1 As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt1.Load(rs1)
        AccountComboBoxDropdown.ValueMember = "Name"
        AccountComboBoxDropdown.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

My Account Table also has a column called "Type" which I want to use to define a picture (each pic file will reside in the project folder with the same name as the type column i.e cash.png, Revolving.png... etc) for each account type:

```
  Accounts Table
 ----------------------------
  Name              Type
 ----------------------------
  Cash Account 1    Cash
  Credit Card 1     Revolving
  Mortgage 1        Mortgage
  Car Loan 1        Vehicle
```

The image on the left is what I currently have, my goal is to get something like the image on the right:

[image]

Is it possible using the data reader?

Thanks in Advance;

Comment: Yes it is possible.  It seems like you'd want something like the Account Type/Code to key off of for the image, but otherwise you need to make the CBO `OwnerDraw` and draw the image and text.  The DataRead is not involved because it has nothing to do with reading data.

Comment: So You mean the images are added after the comboBox is filled from the DataReader?

Comment: And Yes, I want to 'key off of' the Account Type/Code for the image. So how do I coordinate that in my method? Do I somehow append the picture after the combo box is populated with the names? Not too sure how to code this because the names populated from the datareader doesn't seem to be an interruptible iterative process... just seems to populate the combo box with the column in one shot...

Comment: Do some research on *ComboBox* and *OwnerDraw*.  There are hundreds of **[VB posts here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMAWW.png)** showing how. You dont include the image, you *draw* it.  I like to use an `Interface` but I like reusable, flexible and extensible solutions

Comment: So how would you get the key part working? meaning how do I code in the drawEvent to look at the text it's drawing (name) in order to choose what picture from the (Type)? Would I have to output the query results used to generate the comboBox Values in a vector somewhere and use that in the DrawEvent? What is the best approach here?

Comment: `"SELECT Name, Type from Accounts"`

Comment: Yes... so I've used a DataTable.Select method to lookup a value to get the key but how do I grab the value the Draw Event is currently doing? I've tried using `DirectCast(sender,System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox).[Text]` but it seems to only grab the first value in the combobox... I need to pregressively get the items to get their Keys. Any Ideas?

Comment: You should update your post with your efforts so we can see what all this looks like.  It sounds like you have gone off the tracks with "grab", lookup, and ComboBox.Text